# CRC calculation output

Tags: c++, boost, crc

Is 0 a possible checksum for a cyclic redundancy check (CRC)?

I'm using boost to calculate a CRC:

```
const unsigned int CrcPolynomial = 0x11021;
const unsigned short InitialValue = 0xffff;
boost::crc_optimal<16, CrcPolynomial, InitialValue, 0, true, true> Crc;
// process some bytes...
int x = Crc.checksum(); // <------ can this be 0?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Take any message, `x`, and compute its CRC, `crc(x)`.  Then `crc(x . crc(x))` will be 0 (where `.` denotes concatenation).

In fact, this relationship can be used to verify that a message + CRC has been transmitted correctly (see for instance the second animated diagram at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC).

Comment: "Then crc(x . crc(x)) will be 0". This is only true for the basic CRC algorithm, without negating bits or reversing bits. See this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112733/checking-crc32-of-zero-padded-bitstream/6672972#6672972